# Attribute selector a[href=#example] no longer working after updating jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

```
$('a[href=#InterventionEditDocs]').trigger('click');
```

This line of code was working for my project perfectly a few days back but after some updates or something it throws an error in the console.

I fixed it by adding quotes around the value:

```
$('a[href="#InterventionEditDocs"]').trigger('click');
```

and it is now working. But why was it working before, and why do I have to quote the value for it to work again?

Comment: [`To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar"). The W3C CSS specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS character escape sequences for identifiers.`](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: `$('a[href=\\#InterventionEditDocs]').trigger('click');`

Comment: also, your question title mentions `[attribute$=value]` yet the question itself only uses `[attribute=value]`

Comment: You must have updated jQuery library

Answer (score 3):

> But why was it working before

This was a bug with jQuery that was fixed in 1.12.0 and 2.2.0.

`a[href=#InterventionEditDocs]` is an invalid CSS selector, because `#` is a special character (representing an ID selector), and therefore cannot appear in an ident. It never should have worked in jQuery in the first place, and would have resulted in a SYNTAX_ERR if put through `document.querySelectorAll()`.

> and why do I have to quote the value for it to work again?

`a[href="#InterventionEditDocs"]` is valid, because the attribute value is now quoted, and therefore no longer an ident but a string.