# In BeautifulSoup 4.7.0+, how can I select all elements that don't contain the specified text in one of their properties

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I want to select all anchor tags that do not contain `mailto:` in their `href` property.

Up until version 4.7.0 of BeautifulSoup, I was able to use this code:

```
links = soup.select("a[href^=mailto:]")
```

Version 4.7.0 of BeautifulSoup replaced their CSS selector implementation with SoupSieve, which is supposed to be more modern and complete.

Unfortunately, the above code now throws this error:

```
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed attribute selector
```

What is the drop-in replacement for that code? What is the proper way to target those same elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the colon in the `href`'s value [just needed to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973243/attribute-selector-ahref-example-no-longer-working-after-updating-jquery).

You can do that by escaping the individual character:

```
soup.select("a[href^=mailto\\:]")
```

Or by quoting the whole value:

```
soup.select('a[href^="mailto:"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

IE < 8 doesn't recognize that escape `\:` so worth knowing you can also use code points. Also, you want to negate to exclude with `:not` (bs4 4.7.1+)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a href="mailto:NotMe@somewhere.com" target="_blank">Nada</a> 
  <a href="https://www.address.com" target="_blank">Tada</a>
 </body>
</html>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select('[href]:not([href*=mailto\\3A])'))
```

N.B. In browser would be `[href*=mailto\3A]`